# changing sheet address in formula

Tags: excel

Let us suppose  we have following  table :
[image]

and sheet names from L1 to L8, i want to go through L1 to L8 and extract specific element, for instance  i have implemented one of them

```
=INDEX('L2'!$A$12:$H$59,MATCH(E$11,$E$11:$AI$11,0),MATCH("Payment",example!$F$6:$F$9,0)+1)
```

it will take element from L2, but my question is : how to change  L2 according   list ?(L1 to L8)i have try different combination but it does not work, i try code function, concatenate functions but no effect yet, thanks in advance

Comment: `INDIRECT()` function is needed here. Note that as it is a volatile function, it will keep recalculating every time there is a change in any open workbook.

Comment: i have tried it but exactly how should i apply it?

Comment: For example: I have two sheets named as `L1` & `L2` in summary sheet in cell `A1` & `A2`  I have those two sheet names and in cell `B1` i have used this formula to extract data from the respective sheets with reference to the cell. `=INDIRECT("'"&A1&"'!A1:A10")` this is the usual syntax, actually I am not able to reproduce, because i dont see row labels and column headings clearly.

Comment: =INDEX(INDIRECT(C12)!$A$12:$H$59,MATCH(E$11,$E$11:$AI$11,0),MATCH("Payment",example!$F$6:$F$9,0)+1) this i have tried but there is errors

Comment: And if you are using `MS365` you could try using `VSTACK()`  but again, i dont see other sheet sample, so i am guessing, bt the syntax will be like this :`=VSTACK('L1:L2'!A1:A4)`

Comment: Could you post a sample data using **[Markdown_Table_Generator](https://tabletomarkdown.com/convert-spreadsheet-to-markdown/)**

Comment: i think it is private and that why, so using index and match and indirect  is impossible?

Comment: I tried to create a sample on my end, and use this formula, you might need to change as per your suit: **[Look_Here](https://imgur.com/gallery/tBSDuYO)** --> `=INDEX(INDIRECT("'"&$A2&"'!A2:E100"),MATCH($A$1,INDIRECT("'"&$A2&"'!A2:A100"),0),MATCH(B$1,INDIRECT("'"&$A2&"'!A1:E1"),0))`

Comment: thanks it writes following  : #SPILL!

Comment: Try to evaluate the formula, it will help you to understand why is it returning `#SPILL`.

Comment: =INDEX("'"&D12&"'!$A$12:$H$59,MATCH(E$11,$E$11:$AI$11,0),MATCH(""Payment",example!$F$6:$F$9,0)+1 i have changed this way  excel format is exactly  like yours, but   this problem is unclear

Comment: if we seperately evaluate this line :"'"&D12&"'"  then it writes 'L1' but in formula it does not work

Comment: This is the excel sample sheet. I have used. **[Check](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlEkksoPTc2ckwdpxVc_K14hE2qB?e=weK6VC)**

Comment: =INDEX("'"&D12&"'!$A$12:$H$59",4,4) this line evaluated seperately evalues error #REF

Comment: if i dont insert into formula, then ="'"&D12&"'!$A$12:$H$59"  this will return correct address

Comment: better  to do manually, it is clear that something  is strange, thanks for help

Comment: Is there any leading or trailing spaces in the sheet names ?

Comment: no no, it is very late my friend  dont worry good night

Comment: In `E12` try `=INDEX(INDIRECT("'"&D12&"'!$A$12:$H$59"),MATCH(E$11,$E$11:$AI$11,0),MATCH("Payment",example!$F$6:$F$9,0)+1)` and copy down and to the right.